# go routine for range over channels

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

I have been working in Golang for a long time. But still I am facing this problem though I know the solution to my problem. But never figured out why is it happening.

For example If I have a pipeline situation for inbound and outbound channels like below:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    for n := range sq(sq(gen(3, 4))) {
        fmt.Println(n)
    }
    fmt.Println("Process completed")
}

func gen(nums ...int) <-chan int {
    out := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        for _, n := range nums {
            out <- n
        }
        close(out)
    }()
    return out
}

func sq(in <-chan int) <-chan int {
    out := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        for n := range in {
            out <- n * n
        }
        close(out)
    }()
    return out
}
```

It does not give me a deadlock situation. But if I remove the go routine inside the outbound code as below:

```
func sq(in <-chan int) <-chan int {
    out := make(chan int)
    for n := range in {
        out <- n * n
    }
    close(out)
    return out
}
```

I received a deadlock error. Why is it so that looping over channels using range without go routine gives a deadlock.

Answer (score 3):

This situation caused of output channel of `sq` function is not buffered. So `sq` is waiting until next function will read from output, but if `sq` is not async, it will not happen ([Playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/enUHineH7QX)):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func main() {
    numsCh := gen(3, 4)
    sqCh := sq(numsCh) // if there is no sq in body - we are locked here until input channel will be closed
    result := sq(sqCh) // but if output channel is not buffered, so `sq` is locked, until next function will read from output channel

    for n := range result {
        fmt.Println(n)
    }
    fmt.Println("Process completed")
}

func gen(nums ...int) <-chan int {
    out := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        for _, n := range nums {
            out <- n
        }
        close(out)
    }()
    return out
}

func sq(in <-chan int) <-chan int {
    out := make(chan int, 100)
    for n := range in {
        out <- n * n
    }
    close(out)
    return out
}
```

Comment: I remove the goroutine in `sq` which was what was actually asked about (your answer still solves the problem). Please re-edit if I changed your intent.

Comment: This does not provide my answer. My question was why we are not getting deadlock on wrapping the inbound channels inside go routine. This has nothing to do with the buffer. In buffered channels the channel will add the data to the buffer when receiver is not available.

Comment: it's all about different flows of sync and async programms. in case of 'go' keyword usage the program can transfer control of program execution to another goroutine, so buffer can be freed.

`Sync:`
`1) Write to channel`
`2) Write to channel - blocked`
and the async usage can be like
`Async:`
`1) Write to channel`
`2) Read from channel`
`3) Write to channel`
`4) Read from channel`

Answer (score 2):

Your function creates a channel, writes to it, then returns it.  The writing will block until somebody can read the corresponding value, but that's impossible because nobody outside this function has the channel yet.

```
func sq(in <-chan int) <-chan int {
    // Nobody else has this channel yet...
    out := make(chan int)
    for n := range in {
        // ...but this line will block until somebody reads the value...
        out <- n * n
    }
    close(out)
    // ...and nobody else can possibly read it until after this return.
    return out
}
```

If you wrap the loop in a goroutine then both the loop and the `sq` function are allowed to continue; even if the loop blocks, the `return out` statement can still go and eventually you'll be able to connect up a reader to the channel.

(There's nothing intrinsically bad about looping over channels outside of goroutines; your `main` function does it harmlessly and correctly.)

Comment: Thanks but I am still not getting it. I know the reason behind the deadlock. But using go routine will let me range over channels. And one more question comes to my mind now why is it working in the main. It will be appreciated if you provide an reference example for the reason behind do's and don't's.

Comment: You're not getting a deadlock with a goroutine because the writes are in the goroutine. That goroutine blocks, the outer function returns the channel, the caller of that func starts reading from it, and the inner goroutine is then able to send on it.

Comment: @Adrian thanks for your comment but It  is our assumption. It is not mentioned anywhere inside the docs. Also If I knew that it will help my or anyone in future to know how actually channels wait even if there is no buffer or no value is coming from other end. I have experimented a lot. For example have a look at this https://play.golang.org/p/owLc5QoAROa.

Comment: The relevant facts are definitely mentioned, ie that channel operations can block, and that goroutines run concurrently. Your specific example is just an application of those fundamentals.

Answer (score 0):

The reason of the deadlock is because the main is waiting for the `sq` return and finish, but the `sq` is waiting for someone read the chan then it can continue.

I simplified your code by removing layer of sq call, and split one sentence into 2 :

```
func main() {
    result := sq(gen(3, 4)) // <-- block here, because sq doesn't return
    for n := range result { 
        fmt.Println(n)
    }
    fmt.Println("Process completed")
}

func gen(nums ...int) <-chan int {
    out := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        for _, n := range nums {
            out <- n
        }
        close(out)
    }()
    return out
}

func sq(in <-chan int) <-chan int {
    out := make(chan int)
    for n := range in {
        out <- n * n   // <-- block here, because no one is reading from the chan
    }
    close(out)
    return out
}
```

In sq method, if you put code in `goroutine`, then the `sq` will returned, and main func will not block, and consume the result queue, and the `goroutine` will continue, then there is no block any more.

```
func main() {
    result := sq(gen(3, 4)) // will not blcok here, because the sq just start a goroutine and return
    for n := range result {
        fmt.Println(n)
    }
    fmt.Println("Process completed")
}

func gen(nums ...int) <-chan int {
    out := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        for _, n := range nums {
            out <- n
        }
        close(out)
    }()
    return out
}

func sq(in <-chan int) <-chan int {
    out := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        for n := range in {
            out <- n * n // will not block here, because main will continue and read the out chan
        }
        close(out)
    }()
    return out
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is a bit complicated,
Let's simplify

First eq below, not has deadLock

```
func main() {
    send := make(chan int)
    receive := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        send<-3
        send<-4
        close(send)
    }()
    go func() {
        receive<- <-send
        receive<- <-send
        close(receive)
    }()
    for v := range receive{
        fmt.Println(v)

    }
}
```

Second eq below,remove "go" has deadLock

```
func main() {
    send := make(chan int)
    receive := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        send<-3
        send<-4
        close(send)
    }()
    receive<- <-send
    receive<- <-send
    close(receive)
    for v := range receive{
        fmt.Println(v)

    }
}
```

Let's simplify second code again

```
func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)
    ch <- 3
    ch <- 4
    close(ch)
    for v := range ch{
        fmt.Println(v)

    }
}
```

The reason of the deadlock is no buffer channel waiting in main goroutine.

Two Solutions

```
// add more cap then "channel<-" time
func main() {
    ch := make(chan int,2)
    ch <- 3
    ch <- 4
    close(ch)
    for v := range ch{
        fmt.Println(v)

    }
}

//async "<-channel"
func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        for v := range ch {
            fmt.Println(v)
        }
    }()
    ch <- 3
    ch <- 4
    close(ch)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is
when the main thread is blocked for waiting for the chan to be writen or read, Go will detect if any other Go routine is running. If there is no any other Go routine running, it will have "fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!"
I tested if by using the below simple case

```
func main() {
    c := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
    }()
    c <- 1
}
```

The deadlock error is reported after 10 seconds.